# Finding cosets of $(R_{3}[x],+)$ with a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let H be a subgroup of $(R_{3}[x],+)$ with H being defined as ${(x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)f(x) :}$ where f(x) is in $R_{3}[x]$

How would I begin to find the cosets here?

I know that $(x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$ would be a coset since its $(x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$ multiplied by the identity. But i'm not sure how one would begin to find the rest of the cosets of H.

If i understand this correctly, whould I do it by multiplying $(x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$ different elements of $R_{3}[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the subgroup you are finding the cosets for but still in the whole process in this question you don't have to use multiplication because the group's binary operation is (+) pls define the subgroup because the subgroup you have defined is the group itself ,if you use the same subgroup for this it have unique coset the group itself

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The subgroup $H$ contains $(x^3+x^2+x+1)(x-1)x^k$.